# macOS High Sierra 10.13 briefly flashes screen content last seen before locking the screen when awaken

Tags: macos, security, high-sierra, bug, screen-lock

On macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, when I manually lock the screen (shift+ctrl+power) and later press any key to turn it on, the screen content which was shown at the time I locked the screen is briefly displayed on the screen (something like 1/30 or 1/60 of a second — I can measure it with high speed camera but it doesn't matter much) before it finally displays the login UI.

I've never seen it before High Sierra, but now I can reproduce this 100% of the time. This is really annoying because this might allow a stranger to capture screen contents which were shown immediately before the screen was locked.

I found one workaround which is far from perfect: lock the screen, wake up and press 'esc' to turn off the screen again. Then at the next wake up, nothing is revealed.

If I use cmd+ctrl+Q to lock the session as suggested in comments, it makes the bug less frequent, but **doesn't really solve it. In other words it turns a suicide self shot into a Russian Roulette.**

- macOS 10.13.3 is affected
- not fixed in macOS 10.13.4.
- not fixed in macOS 10.13.4 with Security Update 2018-001.
- not fixed in macOS 10.13.5.
- I think I saw it again in macOS 10.13.6 too.

Are there any better workarounds? Is it worth reporting to Apple as a security/privacy bug?

Comment: Use lock screen instead. You are using “power off screen” which does not lock it, the lock is a side effect of the screen going off. Locking is something like cmd-ctrl-q

Comment: @JohnKeates perhaps I should. This doesn't turn it off though, apparently having one key combo to (properly) lock the user session and turn the screen off is too much of a luxury.

Comment: If you press escape after locking, the screen goes black :) So ctrl-cmd-q and then esc is the ultimate combination

Comment: @JohnKeates yes I know, that's what I do.

Comment: I used to experience this same problem on my MacBook Pro (13”, mid-2009). I think it stopped when I upgraded from Yosemite (10.10) to El Capitan (10.11). I saw it as a security flaw, and I’m surprised that someone is experiencing it with one of the newer versions of macOS.

Comment: I also have this issue with High Sierra. It seems to occur every time on waking after the display goes to sleep. I expected it would be quickly resolved - especially if it is widespread - but now many updates later it's still occurring. Did you find a way to effectively notify Apple of the issue? The Apple security page doesn't provide a clear mechanism for reporting bugs that I can see.

Comment: @Huacanacha I reported it as a security issue by email (exactly as described). They still tell me "we are checking …", "working on it", etc.

Comment: I just got a similar reply from Apple via that security email:
"Hello Jason,

Thank you for your report. We are aware of this issue and the appropriate teams are working on a resolution.

Best regards,
Jonathan
Apple Product Security"

Comment: Update: Still happens regularly on my macOS Mojave 10.14.6 machines, too. But, I don't think I've seen it (yet?) on macOS Catalina.

Comment: I have seen it on Catalina.

Comment: Still in 10.15.7, just figured would re-google if anything was known and found this.

Comment: Here’s hoping Monterey, Big Sur and Catalina  have  tightened this up for many people … https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - the frame buffer should be scrubbed / discarded as part of the sleep / lock process no matter how brief the render. I don't think it's a huge risk and can be mitigated as you say by logging out of the screen before locking or any number of other ways like timed lockouts.

This may be fixed in [Monterey 12.3, Big Sur and Catalina as CVE-2022-22656](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213183)

I'd just log out or enable fast user switching and switch away from the screen instead of letting the screen saver lock.

Apple publishes a page with instructions on how to report issues. If this were a huge gap, I'd consider asking you to delete the thread, but I don't think this is "stop the planet" serious unless there's a way to abuse this "feature".

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201220

> **Security and privacy researchers**
>
> To report security or privacy issues that affect Apple products or web
> servers, please contact product-security@apple.com.

Comment: okay… I've sent them a message to `product-security@apple.com`, hopefully they will do something

Comment: so it's been 1 or 2 macOS updates from the time I've sent them a detailed report, and I didn't get any valuable replies from them, and the bug is still not fixed. :/

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work like this.

Comment: This appears to be fixed as of yesterday's release of macOS Mojave.

Comment: I'm on 10.14.4 and still seeing it.

Comment: Still doing it on 10.14.5 on a Mid-2014 15" MacBook Pro. It never did this on 10.11.

Comment: "I don't think it's a huge risk"; not a risk perhaps but unambiguously a privacy breach. All manner of sensitive information might be leaked through this. IMO Apple should be roasted for such inattention to their software quality, year after year. It's now 2020 and still not fixed.